# Excel Macro to add a row of sums under each column

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am very new to excel macros and I think this one is beyond my abilities. I have an Excel file where I have a String ID column in column A, and data (as a Double) in columns B,C,D, and E. I want to Macro to read column A, every time it says "switch", I want it to insert a row beneath it, and write the word "TOTAL" in column A, and Sum the above entries for columns B,C,D, and E, respectively. Every row of sums should only include from the previous 'TOTAL' row down to the one being written. If I can clarify in any way please let me know - I have found some useful questions that were already asked here but none that helped me enough to write this one myself. Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: You don't need a macro to do this. Look up information on Excel's subtotal feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub macro1()

Dim sum1 As Integer
sum1 = 0
totalRowsInExcel = Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
i = 2

While (i <= totalRowsInExcel)

  If (Cells(i, 1).Value <> "TOTAL") Then
    sum1 = sum1 + Cells(i, 2).Value
  End If

  If (Cells(i, 1).Value = "switch") Then
    Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + 1).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A" & i + 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "TOTAL"
    Range("B" & i + 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = sum1
    sum1 = 0
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    totalRowsInExcel = Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

  End If
 i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub
```